# How to avoid losing object this context in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects, this

I have created a getter field on a class that returns a method, which is invoked with some inputs. Here is the method:

```js
private gainItem(rewardItem: Item) {
  console.log(this);
  //Give item to user
}
```

Here is the getter field on the class containing this method:

```js
private get npcPlayerInterface(): NpcPlayerInterface {
  return {
    gainItem: this.gainItem,
  };
}
```

I then pass the getter to another class like this:

```js
this.npcChatState = new NpcChatState(this.npcPlayerInterface);
```

Finally, this is how it is invoked inside the `npcChatState` class:

```js
npcPlayerInterface.gainItem({ id: ItemId.CAR_BLUE, name: 'Blue CAR' });
```

The `console.log(this)` statement shows that the `this` keyword refers to another object, not the one that I want. How can I fix this without using `bind()` or this-aliasing?

Comment: You have multiple code blocks that are not clearly presented together: which one belongs to a class, and which one refers to the class being consumed? Can you create a [mcve] in your question instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use arrow syntax:

```js
private gainItem = (rewardItem: Item) => {
    console.log(this);
}
```